# increase superset sqllab timeout

Tags: sql, timeout, apache-superset

How to increase sqllab timeout in apache superset? I have tried increasing SUPERSET_TIMEOUT but this does not work. Query gets timedout in 30 secs. I am not able to run a complex query.

Answer (score 1):

See https://superset.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#why-are-my-queries-timing-out for possible reasons for queries to time out, and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the time out parameter in File **config.py**
file path `lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset-0.30.1-py3.7.egg/superset`

> #Timeout duration for SQL Lab synchronous queries
>
> SQLLAB_TIMEOUT = 30

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Superset 0.23.3 on HDP 3.1.0) adding this configuration option to `superset_config.py` increased the timeout:

```
SQLLAB_TIMEOUT=120
```

Also, keep in mind that `SUPERSET_TIMEOUT` should be equal or greater to the above number, otherwise gunicorn will drop the request before it finishes.